# Prefabs & scripts missing after using source control to move Unity project to a different machine

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine

I've been working on a small project in Unity over the past few months, using Git for source control along the way. I recently got a new laptop which is being demo my progress in different locations.

I installed Unity & all the relevant runtimes needed within the application and pulled the source down to the new machine. The project opens in Unity, but the Hierarchy view shows this where my prefabs used to be.

[image]

All of the resources (prefabs, models, scripts) are in the same directories as they were on the original development machine, but are somehow becoming "unlinked" during the process of pulling them down to a new machine.

I have tried searching but have been unable to find a solution to this particular problem shy of just recreating everything.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you enabled visible .meta files in your project?  I know they are supposed to be on when using version control.  This could have something to do with your issue.

Comment: Close Unity and try removing `Library` folder from the file system. This should cause Unity to restore references within project (and recreate the `Library` folder).

Comment: i'm pretty sure your problem is SOMETHING to do with meta files - either what James says, or some other meta file issue.  for example did you accidentally EXCLUDE meta files from the git?  dude this is why subversion is so popular and easy for unity projects  :/

Comment: btw please google exactly "unity3d prefab missing" for many discussions on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are meta files associated with all your assets inside of a Unity Project, which is why any kind of external version control / source control does not save all of those settings, because they're not being linked correctly. If available to you at all, the included Asset Server within Unity ( read source control ) is extremely easy to setup, and has worked perfectly fine for me ( with a small team ).

If you're absolutely set on using git, take a look at Unity's documentation below to see if it will clear up your problems:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html

Comment: Yep, nailed it. Meta files were visible and I had made sure that the Unity section of our gitignore wasn't causing the problem, but another section of the gitignore file was inadvertently ignoring the meta files after all. So obvious in retrospect. Many thanks.

Comment: New link is: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html